# Exception The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me with this error

> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted

My code is:

```
alter trigger t1 
on Client 
after insert, update
as
begin
    if (exists (select cincli from inserted 
               intersect 
               select cincli from Client))
        rollback transaction
end
```

I don't know where the problem is?

Comment: The "problem" if that the `IF` evaluates to TRUE, and therefore the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: @Larnu can you help me please

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to achieve? I can tell you why you're getting the error, I can't tell you how to do what you're trying to do without know what that is.

Comment: @Larnu hahaha I'm so sorry I'm a newbie in sql I want if i insert an id and if this id is alerdy exist  my program do a rollback I know there is multiple methode to do that but the teacher ask me to do it like that

Comment: Why not just use a Primary Key..? And have the RDBMS handle the generation of the ID, possibly?

Comment: @Larnu Thank you so much yes I can do that but the problem why rollback doesn't work

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work"? It clearly *is* working.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). There is an example of using a trigger to enforce a rule. Use it as an example. Your biggest problem is that you roll the transaction back but the calling application has no idea why and tries to commit the transaction - which it can't and causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, don't use a `TRIGGER` to check if there is a duplicate value. Considering you're talking about the ID, then a `PRIMARY KEY` seems like the correct choice:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (cincli);
```

If `cincli` is not always ascending, you likely want a `NONCLUSTERED` Primary Key, and instead should create a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on a column that *is* always ascending.